# How to dial to a number automaticall with out opening the dialer

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova

Im using phonegap to create an android app. I need to invoke one touch call from application so that user can directly call. I used **< a href='tel:xxxx...' >** but it still opens Android Dialer dialog box from there user need to press the call button to initial call.. Can we remove this intermediate dialer and directly call to a number?

Comment: see http://rickluna.com/wp/2012/02/making-a-phone-call-from-within-phonegap-in-android-and-ios/

Answer (score 1):

No you can not call directly. For that you have to go for native code. But HTML5 and Cordova doesn't supports. We can't remove this intermediate dialer and can't directly call to a number.

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:xxxx..."));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

context.startActivity(intent);
```

This code will dial without need to press call button.

**Tested on Android 2.3.6**